# Android: Handle Configuration Changes Inside fragment

Tags: android, android-configchanges

I have saved the list in savedInstance method but it is coming zero size when conf is changed.
Below is my code:

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            if(savedInstanceState == null) {
                arrayListPLPDetails = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            else
            {
                arrayListPLPDetails =  (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(Tag.SAVED_INSTANCE)  ;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putSerializable(Tag.SAVED_INSTANCE,arrayListPLPDetails);
        }
```

Comment: try removing `setRetainInstance(true);`

Comment: why not used restored to fetch value?

Comment: How to use restored to fetch values?

Answer (score 1):

Override the method " onConfigurationChanged " inside fragment.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

  // Checks the orientation of the screen
  if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
      Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Check the following link

[Android Docs for Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Answer (score -1):

When the setRetainInstance(true) method is called in onCreate() method, onCreate() and onDestroy () methods are skipped, so it can't put some initail  logic in onCreate().

Comment: didnt understood your last line. Please explain?

Comment: can't put some initialization logic in onCreate() method

Comment: Then what is the solution of my problem

Comment: try moving `onCreate()`  to `onStart()`